# Unable to find javascript file in navigator in Chrome developer tools

Tags: javascript, debugging, axios, google-chrome-devtools

How would I find this file if it didn't has breackpoint in it? Filename is `axios-setToken.js` and it is displayed in top tab, but not in navigator.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you press <kbd>Ctrl+P</kbd> and start typing the filename, devtools should find the file and list it below; clicking it opens it. I use that often when files aren't listed in the navigation pane for whatever reason.

You see a message about this when there are no open editors:

[image: devtools showing various comments, including Ctrl+_P]

Here for instance I've opened devtools on this SO page, opened a file (just to show that <kbd>Ctrl+P</kbd> works even when there's already an editor open), and typed the first three letters of "jQuery" since I know SO uses jQuery:

[image: devtools showing a match for the string "jqu"]

As you can see, it found `jquery.min.js` for me.

This is often handy even when files *are* listed in the navigator.